# Hide option from select using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have three select drop down. If I select one option from one drop down then that options should be hidden from the other two drop downs. My code is given below-

```
<select name="item_code" id="item_code1">
    <option value="code1">Code1</option>
    <option value="code2">Code2</option>
    <option value="code3">Code3</option>
</select>
<select name="item_code" id="item_code2">
    <option value="code1">Code1</option>
    <option value="code2">Code2</option>
    <option value="code3">Code3</option>
</select>
<select name="item_code" id="item_code3">
    <option value="code1">Code1</option>
    <option value="code2">Code2</option>
    <option value="code3">Code3</option>
</select>
```

Can anybody tell me how to write a jquery function for doing this job. Here the select drop down is dynamic where there is no limit that the select drop downs are only three, It may be more than three.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - disable/enable select options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629669/jquery-disable-enable-select-options)

Answer (score 0):

Like this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6qM3F/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/rJ98a/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/K36Dm/

*OR** http://jsfiddle.net/H8TD3/ (Show and hide both)

further ideas:

- you could use `.not` api for not hiding in the current `select` http://api.jquery.com/not/
- you can also do enable disable which makes more sense. like this: [jQuery - disable/enable select options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629669/jquery-disable-enable-select-options)

rest should fit the need.

**Code**

```
$(function () {
    $('select').change(function() {
        $(" option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").hide();
    });
});
```

**code**

```
$(function () {
    var theValue;
    $('select').focus(function () {
        theValue = $(this).val();
    });
    $('select[name="item_code"]').change(function () {
        $("select[name='item_code'] option[value='" + theValue + "']").show();
        $("select[name='item_code'] option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. Its working... But I have another select drop down named item_category... This javascript function is affecting that select drop down also.. But it should not affect item_category drop down..

Comment: @user2998739 like this **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/rJ98a/ **or** this http://jsfiddle.net/K36Dm/  `:)`

Comment: Now another problem occurs... If I select another option then the previous hidden option is not shown. How to show the hidden option again?

Comment: @user2998739 Okies, first you should try something but anyhoo **this will help you now** exactly what you need **Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/H8TD3/ and *dont forget to accept the answer* `:))` have FUN!! Dont forget to remove that alert in the code `:)`

Comment: It is useful for only for the first drop down... How to make it useful for all the drop downs?

Comment: @user2998739 you are missing basics of Jquery, I cannot teach you everything unless you show me your effort, what do you mean by one? I did shared some ideas with you in the post,! Try them first, perhaps spend some time learning http://api.jquery.com/. Sorry I dont get your question, what is not working now? It is working for me for all the drop downs : http://jsfiddle.net/vX3B4/

Comment: Ok... I will try... My problem is that if I select an option from the first drop down it is hidden from all the drop downs. But if I select another option from the second drop down then that option is not hidden from the third drop down.

Comment: @user2998739 awesome! `:)` glad I can help and sorry if i said anything unreasonable, idea was to warm up your brain as well! `:)`