# Select option validation for start and end time

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Select START time**

```
<select name="start-time">
<option value="00:00 am" selected="selected">00:00 am</option><option value="00:30 am">00:30 am</option><option value="01:00 am">01:00 am</option><option value="01:30 am">01:30 am</option><option value="02:00 am">02:00 am</option><option value="02:30 am">02:30 am</option><option value="03:00 am">03:00 am</option><option value="03:30 am">03:30 am</option><option value="04:00 am">04:00 am</option><option value="04:30 am">04:30 am</option><option value="05:00 am">05:00 am</option><option value="05:30 am">05:30 am</option><option value="06:00 am">06:00 am</option><option value="06:30 am">06:30 am</option><option value="07:00 am">07:00 am</option><option value="07:30 am">07:30 am</option><option value="08:00 am">08:00 am</option><option value="08:30 am">08:30 am</option><option value="09:00 am">09:00 am</option><option value="09:30 am">09:30 am</option><option value="10:00 am">10:00 am</option><option value="10:30 am">10:30 am</option><option value="11:00 am">11:00 am</option><option value="11:30 am">11:30 am</option><option value="12:00 pm">12:00 pm</option><option value="12:30 pm">12:30 pm</option><option value="13:00 pm">13:00 pm</option><option value="13:30 pm">13:30 pm</option><option value="14:00 pm">14:00 pm</option><option value="14:30 pm">14:30 pm</option><option value="15:00 pm">15:00 pm</option><option value="15:30 pm">15:30 pm</option><option value="16:00 pm">16:00 pm</option><option value="16:30 pm">16:30 pm</option><option value="17:00 pm">17:00 pm</option><option value="17:30 pm">17:30 pm</option><option value="18:00 pm">18:00 pm</option><option value="18:30 pm">18:30 pm</option><option value="19:00 pm">19:00 pm</option><option value="19:30 pm">19:30 pm</option><option value="20:00 pm">20:00 pm</option><option value="20:30 pm">20:30 pm</option><option value="21:00 pm">21:00 pm</option><option value="21:30 pm">21:30 pm</option><option value="22:00 pm">22:00 pm</option><option value="22:30 pm">22:30 pm</option><option value="23:00 pm">23:00 pm</option><option value="23:30 pm">23:30 pm</option></select>
```

**Select END time**

```
<select name="end-time">
<option value="00:00 am" selected="selected">00:00 am</option><option value="00:30 am">00:30 am</option><option value="01:00 am">01:00 am</option><option value="01:30 am">01:30 am</option><option value="02:00 am">02:00 am</option><option value="02:30 am">02:30 am</option><option value="03:00 am">03:00 am</option><option value="03:30 am">03:30 am</option><option value="04:00 am">04:00 am</option><option value="04:30 am">04:30 am</option><option value="05:00 am">05:00 am</option><option value="05:30 am">05:30 am</option><option value="06:00 am">06:00 am</option><option value="06:30 am">06:30 am</option><option value="07:00 am">07:00 am</option><option value="07:30 am">07:30 am</option><option value="08:00 am">08:00 am</option><option value="08:30 am">08:30 am</option><option value="09:00 am">09:00 am</option><option value="09:30 am">09:30 am</option><option value="10:00 am">10:00 am</option><option value="10:30 am">10:30 am</option><option value="11:00 am">11:00 am</option><option value="11:30 am">11:30 am</option><option value="12:00 pm">12:00 pm</option><option value="12:30 pm">12:30 pm</option><option value="13:00 pm">13:00 pm</option><option value="13:30 pm">13:30 pm</option><option value="14:00 pm">14:00 pm</option><option value="14:30 pm">14:30 pm</option><option value="15:00 pm">15:00 pm</option><option value="15:30 pm">15:30 pm</option><option value="16:00 pm">16:00 pm</option><option value="16:30 pm">16:30 pm</option><option value="17:00 pm">17:00 pm</option><option value="17:30 pm">17:30 pm</option><option value="18:00 pm">18:00 pm</option><option value="18:30 pm">18:30 pm</option><option value="19:00 pm">19:00 pm</option><option value="19:30 pm">19:30 pm</option><option value="20:00 pm">20:00 pm</option><option value="20:30 pm">20:30 pm</option><option value="21:00 pm">21:00 pm</option><option value="21:30 pm">21:30 pm</option><option value="22:00 pm">22:00 pm</option><option value="22:30 pm">22:30 pm</option><option value="23:00 pm">23:00 pm</option><option value="23:30 pm">23:30 pm</option></select>
```

Is there any quick jQuery login to disable the previous options in **END Time** if the **Start Time** is Chosen from between.

For example if Start Time is chosen as 3pm and in End Time all the options before 3pm should be disabled.

Is there any easy way to do it in jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629669/jquery-disable-enable-select-options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work using the selected option's index and disabling the other select options up to that index:

```
$('select[name=start-time]').on("change",function(){
    var theSelectedIndex = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
    $.each($('select[name=end-time] option'), function(){
        var endOptionIndex = $(this).index();
        if (endOptionIndex < theSelectedIndex){
           $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        } else{
           $(this).removeAttr('disabled').prop('selected', true);
           return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nUAV3/

Comment: awesome, this works but is there anyway that rather than disable can the previous values be removed?

Comment: changing to `$(this).attr('hidden','hidden');` worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("select[name='start-time']").on("change", function(){
    $("select[name='end-time']").empty();
    var startix = $("select[name='start-time'] option:selected").index();
    $("select[name='start-time'] option").each(function(ix, el){
        if (ix >= startix) {
            $(this).clone().appendTo("select[name='end-time']");
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H6PAL/

Comment: Much more elegant solution @Maurice.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this :

- get `start-time` selected `option` value
- loop through `end-time` `option`s
- disable `end-time`'s `option` if before

`

```
   $("select[name='start-time']").change(function(){
        var startVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        $("select[name='end-time']").find("option").each(function(idx, elem){
            if (checkIfOptionBeforeStartVal(startVal, $(this).val()) // I let you code this compareson function
               $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            else
               $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        });
    });
```

`

Comment: I would love to know why the downvote. I wonder what's wrong.

Comment: I assume its because you have misread the question? when the op says 'For example if Start Time is chosen as 3pm and in End Time all the options before 3pm should be disabled.' they mean don't allow the user to select end time before start time not completely disable the input

Comment: No, it disable the `option` not the `select`, so it disables the option whose value is under 3pm.

Comment: so it does, i missed `.find("option")` i have no idea then

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @staticVoid's answer, do something like

```
$('#start').on("change",function(){
    var select = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
    $('option').removeAttr('disabled');  //in case start time is changed
    $.each($('#end option'), function(){
        var disable = $(this).index();
        if (disable < select){
           $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        } else{
           $(this).removeAttr('disabled').prop('selected', true);
           return false;
        }
    });
});
```

to ensure it works fine when the start time is changed.  [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wTmwM/)

Note:  I have added `id` to both select menus to make it easier to handle.

Also,  you can try to handle the reverse,  i.e., when a user first selects end time,  disable all the time after that in start.