# Disable value dropdown list when click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have code here. I can see that it's disabling but when it submit data it looks like it was refreshing and the disable value are being reset. What is wrong here? the onclick event is for the radio button for submitting vote. This dropdown list are fetching data that comes from the database which is position_name

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#position').change(function() {

  $("#position").prop("disabled", true);

});
 });
</script>
```

and this is the submit dropdown list.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('position_name').value = "<?php echo $_POST['position'];?>";
  </script>
      <div id="container">
       <table width="420" align="center">
        <form name="fmNames" id="fmNames" method="post"  onclick="getPosition(this.value)">
       <tr>
     <td>Choose Position</td>
      <td>
   <SELECT NAME="position" id="position" onchange="form.submit()" onclick="getPosition(this.value)">
       <OPTION VALUE="select">select
       <?php 
          //loop through all table rows
           while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($positions)){
           echo "<OPTION VALUE=$row[position_name]>$row[position_name]"; 

     }
?>
</SELECT></td>
 </tr>
 </form>
```

Comment: Hi this is a knowing question : a simple search give you many answers so one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629669/jquery-disable-enable-select-options

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the definition of the function getPosition? Also, why have an onclick for the form tag?

Comment: okay sir i will

Answer (score 0):

In your `SELECT` you have an `onchange="form.submit()"` that triggers the form to submit the data and subsequently redirect to the page it is meant to send the data to which in your case is the same page.

Remove the `onchange` event to stop the form submitting when you select a position.

Comment: it's disabling now. But the data is not submitting is there any other way? without onchange="form.submit()" i cant submit and get the data that i have been selected on the dropdown

Comment: You are looking for jQuery to send requests without having to refresh the page. An alternative is using PHP sessions to allow the refresh to happen and to check if the dropdown should be disabled or not on certain conditions.